# values not getting updated in webparam.mode.INOUT in JAXWS web services

Tags: java, xml, web-services, jax-ws

I'm calling a web service which is a void web method. The request/response elements are marked as `webparam.mode.INOUT`. When I call this web method with my request and response as same objects, I'm not able to get the response from the Holder(Is it because the request and response are of the same object). My *pseudocode* is something like below.

```
A a = new A();    
B b = new B();    
Holder<A> aHolder = new Holder<A>(a); // JAXWS Holder  
Holder<B> bHolder = new Holder<B>(b);// JAXWS Holder  
InService inservice = new InService();    
InPortType inPortType = inservice.getPortType();    
inPortType.getInfo(aHolder,bHolder);
```

How do I get the response from `aHolder`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a solution to my answer. We can get it from the same INOUT object by using Holder.value. 
It worked for me.